# Missing blocks when sending transactions

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, transactions, rpc

I was trying to create a bot that each block will buy a given token, but when i try to send bunch of transactions with 30ms break in-between I can see that my transactions arent happening each block but every couple of blocks, despite being sent faster than block.

For instance, I sent 100 transactions one after another for a few seconds and I got in with  10 of them in blocks:

```
244276553, 244276548, 244276543, 244276540, 244276537
```

And clearly transactions are spaced by at least 3 blocks in between.

I'm using my own full node RPC that I set up today. Is there anything that I can do to make it work every block?

Comment: How much contention is there between your transactions, and specifically are you buying/selling to the same accounts?

Comment: @CallumM What is contention? And yes there is one wallet that is performing buying/selling.

Comment: Could you post the code to send the transactions? Maybe you are actually confirming the transactions befor you send the next one?

Answer (score 1):

[The person who ultimately determines what transaction gets included in what block is the leader](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/how-are-transactions-stored-and-verified-in-a-block). This means that running your own full-node ensures that your transactions get included when you are the leader (unless other validators purposely collude to vote against it, but this is extremely unlikely). However, when other nodes are the leader, you have no guarantee, as blocks are limited in size and Compute Budget, so not every transaction can be included. You can significantly increase the probability of your transaction being included by setting higher priority fees and/or using [Jito bundles](https://jito-labs.gitbook.io/mev/searcher-resources/bundles), however I don't think there's a way to guarantee a transaction inclusion in every block with 100% certainty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't quite understand why my transactions with high priority fee don't get included. For instance there is [this wallet](https://solscan.io/account/Brj77mdbagcCPo3NWxBLyNqz2oqBiUgL2LNfauMrzCVo) which transactions happen nearly every block, yet mine happen every couple of blocks. And from what I see he is paying 10x smaller fees than I am for my failed transaction.

Also regarding Jito bundles, how often do they happen? Is the MEV market in Solana as big as in ETH? I've seen their MEV Dashboard but I am not sure if it's that big of a deal here.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with ETH as Solana so I can't answer how the MEV market compares, but most arbitrage bots make use Jito to ensure their transactions get included. As for the wallet you linked, I don't know if they use Jito themselves, however I can see that they spam an absolutely enormous amount of transactions, (most of which fail) to get their tx included which is costing them a lot in fees. For them Jito would probably be cheaper, as this is the whole reason it was invented.

Comment: Additionally, priority fees depend on how contested the state you're trying to access is. So if I'm trying to get a tx included that swaps two random memecoins, I can get included for a lower priority fee than you if you're trying to swap SOL and USDC for example, as the accounts controlling that market are likely in more demand. I didn't take a super close look at the wallet you linked, but they're probably also accessing state that is less contested than the one you're trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to land more transactions, here are a few things to keep in mind.

- It's totally normal that you don't land a transaction in every block. Some of those blocks might not even exist because of a delinquent validator.
- If you're sleeping 30ms between each transaction, then you can an only get ~13 transactions in a block max, since blocks are timed to be roughly 400ms. Try only sleeping 10ms to get more transactions in.
- If your RPC node is unstaked or doesn't have an agreement with validators, it might not be much more performant that just using a `TpuClient` from a normal client machine to send transactions at the network. See how many transactions you can land using something like `send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel` https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/d5ab2fa1df07203387a13e98ad94fa4bb5aee053/client/src/send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel.rs#L393